# Why is a klein Bottle 4-D?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, manifolds, klein-bottle

I am wondering why a Klein Bottle is 4-D. Can anybody tell me how it is possible?
I can represent the Klein Bottle in 3-D. Then how can it be 4-D?

What is immersion? What is embedding?
Basically, [Here](https://www.kleinbottle.com/whats_a_klein_bottle.htm) I got the concept.
And also I've watched some videos in [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E8rifKlq5hc) about construction from rectangle strip. Can anybody explain it in a simpler way?

Comment: The 3D Klein bottle isn't a "true" Klein bottle. *Why* isn't possible an embedding of the Klein bottle in $\Bbb R^3$ is hard: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/18987/why-cant-the-klein-bottle-embed-in-mathbbr3.

Answer (score 5):

The Klein bottle is a surface, a two-dimensional manifold, but it can be embedded in $\mathbb{R}^4$ (but not $\mathbb{R}^n$ for any $n < 4$).

Comment: Can you tell me What is embedding, tell me in simple manner. If possible through real world example.

Comment: An embedding of $K$ into $\mathbb{R}^4$ is a way of considering the Klein bottle inside of $\mathbb{R}^4$ without self-intersections. The usual picture in $\mathbb{R}^3$ has self-intersections, so it isn't an embedding, but rather an immersion.